# php: Use different arrays in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I have 3 input that can be added dynamically. So the `name` of input is array, like:

```
<input type="text" name="qty1[]">
<input type="text" name="qty2[]">
<input type="text" name="qty3[]">
```

(Each of these input texts can be generated by javascript)

In my php file, I get them and want to insert to database (my controller in codeigniter):

```
$address = $this->input->post("qty1");
$LocX =    $this->input->post("qty2");
$LocY =    $this->input->post("qty3");
```

In my db part, where I want to use `foreach` and add to database:

**Edit**

```
foreach ($address as $key) {
  // I want to add $LocX and $LocY to the table
  // LocX and LocY are column names.
  $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO address (Comp_ID, Value, LocX, LocY)
                             VALUES(?, ?)", array($Comp_ID, $key ,? ,?));
}
```

I want to add all of them into foreach as parameter. As I searched it's not possible. What shoud I do? Thanks.

**Edit2**

The result of arrays, for example for `$LocX` :

```
Array
(
  [0] => test1
  [1] => test2
  [2] => test3
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add all of them" and "as parameter"?

Comment: @VladimirSerykh `$address` , `$LocX` and `$locY`, all of these variables are arrays. I should use them in foreach in order to insert into database.

Comment: @MattHB yes, something like that.

Comment: What do you want to be the expected output of your array? Before inserting in your database?

Comment: If you want to use them in the same foreach, you could `array_merge()` them. Or just move your foreach to a separate function and call it 3 times.

Comment: `array_merge()` is not preferable in this case, as it will overwrite the keys

Comment: I think get all of your data inside a new array. That's the only way to get all of the separated arrays from your inputs

Comment: @vahid najafi. Can you show me the output of your three variables?

Comment: please check edit part, maybe you didn't understand what I mean.

Comment: @aldrin27 check second edit.

Comment: So you want every variables to stored in an array?

Comment: @aldrin27 no, they are basically array due to `name` of input text. It was solved. Check accepted answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the index in the foreach to get to the other elements. But you need to carefully check if the index value exists in the other arrays (isset check)

For example:

```
foreach ($address as $key => $value) {
  if(isset($LocX[$key], $LocY[$key]) {
      $a_LocX = $LocX[$key]; // This will be the locx of the address
      $a_LocY = $LocY[$key]; // This will be the locy of the address

      // Change your query to fit the table and fill in the locx and y.
      $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO address (Comp_ID, Value)
                             VALUES(?, ?)", array($Comp_ID, $key));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `for` loop for this.

```
$address = $this->input->post("qty1");
$LocX =    $this->input->post("qty2");
$LocY =    $this->input->post("qty3");

$n=count($address);
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
       $a=$address[$i];
       $x=$locX[$i];
       $y=$locY[$i];
       //insert here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use Codeigniter syntax, and this will make your insert work,

```
foreach($address as $k => $v)
{
    $insert = array(
                'Comp_ID' => $Comp_ID,
                'Value' => $v,
            ); // insert array

    if(in_array($LocX[$k], $LocX)) // existance check
        $insert = array_merge($insert, array('LocX' => $LocX[$k]));

    if(in_array($LocY[$k], $LocY)) // existance check
        $insert = array_merge($insert, array('LocY' => $LocY[$k]));

    $this->db->insert('address', $insert); // No need to write full query
}
```